# Publish a short summary of an accepted paper before proceedings

Tags: citations, ethics, paper-submission

A paper I submitted as part of my PhD to an international conference has been recently accepted and I wish to publish a short translated summary to a national conference (which is allowed by them provided that I cite the original paper).

However, the proceedings for the international conference take place after those of the national one. Is it possible to cite the international conference paper before the proceedings?

P.S: My field is computer science

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to cite a paper that is "to appear", even more so if you know where and when. But, both conferences need to be ok with this, so make sure you have all appropriate permissions. Some venues can be fussy.

There probably won't be a problem given that the short paper is just a summary. But it is their rules that apply.

But just mark the citation as "to appear, month, venue".